# Copy/paste multiple values into list box filter

Tags: spotfire

I am very new to Spotfire.

I have a list box filter where I have hundreds of locations to choose from, and need to choose 100+ of these locations (it should be noted that this list is not static, and will change every time I run the report).

Rather than selecting each location individually in the filter, I am looking for a way to copy/paste a list of locations into the filter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In your listbox filter, you can paste a string with this format (by replacing all valueX by their value) :

```
(value1)OR(value2)OR(value3)OR .......
```

Hope it helps, if you have any question don't hesitate ;)